# Angular 8-to-9 migration (WITHOUT Material) index.d.ts module declaration problem

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular9

I have two modules declared in an `index.d.ts` file like this:

```js
declare module 'googlemaps';
declare module 'detect-resize';
```

This used to work just fine so that I'd be able to use these modules.

For `googlemaps` I have a dependency on `@types/googlemaps`, but the `googlemaps` API can't be loaded until runtime, which is done using an API key.

`detect-resize` is simply lacking typing, and needs the `declare` because of that.

Using Angular 8 and earlier, I had no problems with these modules so long as they were declared in `index.d.ts`. With Angular 9, that isn't fixing the problem, and I can't get through a build now.

I've found issues reported with Angular 9 and `index.d.ts`, but they all involve Angular Material, and solving the problem by changing the version of Material used. That's obviously not going to help here.

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I've since found a fix, so I'd have to break the code again to get the exact error. It was basically that the two modules weren't defined or weren't available. Sorry I don't remember the exact wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* this fixes the problem, but it does. My `tsconfig.app.json` file originally looked like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The automatated upgrade from Angular 8 to 9 modified this file like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I had to explicitly declare the `index.d.ts` in the `files` section like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

What confuses me is that the glob in the `include` section (`src/**/*.d.ts`) should match `index.d.ts` (which is at the top of the `src` directory), so why explicitly declaring the `index.d.ts` fixes the problem baffles me a bit.